# Date range validation with Entity Framework 4 data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

I am using Entity Framework 4 to provide the model for a ASP.NET MVC3 / Razor2 web application. I am using DataAnnotations to implement validation. I need to limit some dates to the range accepted by the SQL smalldatetime type.

My problem is that I can't get the RangeAttribute to work correctly for a date field. The model metadata definition for the field in question is:

```
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Patient), Name = "DateOfBirth_Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1900", "06/06/2079", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Patient), ErrorMessageResourceName = "DateOfBirth_Range")] 
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

With this code, whatever value I put into the date field, it is treated as invalid by the application. In case its' relevant, I am using the JQuery-UI date picker with the field in question as well.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not specify where the error occurs, but my guess is that it is client-side(?) jQuery Validation does not work well with the `RangeAttribute`. To verify, disable jQuery Validation and the valid input should pass the (server) validation.

To get around this you will have to write your own date range validation, e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Alternatively you could look into packages such as [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org) or [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com) to see if they could be used for solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Martin4ndersen. Disabling the JS validation libraries for the view enabled correct validation server-side, as you predicted. By itself, the custom attribute showed in the blog gives correct server-side validation, with js enabled. I will take the extra hit to implement the workaround it suggests to get the client-side support working as well. Shame the RangeAttribute and js unobtrusive validation don't work properly together. Would like to see that fixed in a future release of MVC.