# How to implement Date Range Validator in MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to restrict user from entering a date except a particular range in my MVC 4 application. Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what validation framework are you using? are you validating on the client, server or both?

Comment: You have to implement self validated class. Use  IValidatableObject  and take a look here   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Comment: This link will be helpful for date range validation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183647/date-range-validation-with-entity-framework-4-data-annotations

Comment: @JasonMeckley: I have to implement on both server as well as client. I have implemented server side validation by inheriting my class 'DateRangeAttribute' with 'ValidationAttribute' class and it is working fine. But I need it on client side also. So is there a inbuilt or predefined approach to do this?

Comment: @Nikhil: Thanks for your reply, but I have already tried this and it is not working for me.

Comment: You should state in your question that you have implemented server-side validation, and that you need to implement client-side validation.  Otherwise, people will see the C# tag and automatically think server-side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761185/jquery-validate-date-range

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IValidatableObject interface and using Validate method to do this validation.

check [Using IValidatableObject Custom Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx)