# MVC 4 Entity Framework 6.1 DataAnnotationValidator Erroneous Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, entity-framework-6.1

I have a EF model that uses a DataAnnotationValidator.cs as a one stop class for validation.  I like this approach except for date datatypes.  I've found lots of information on validating everything but dates.  How do you validate a date using this technique?  The following displays the date properly, but allows any input with the correct formatting as a valid date:  32/32/2014 passes the test, but 32//2014 doesn't.

I've tried it with and without [DataType(DataType.DateTime)].  I've tried RegularExpression without sucess.  I must be missing something.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(v_Demographics_Metadata))]
 public partial class v_Demographics
 {
 }
 class v_Demographics_Metadata
 {
 [Display(Name = "Date of Birth"), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
 [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
 }
```

UPDATE:  Found this [solution](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/).  Modified it as follows.  Although not exactly what I wanted to do, it works well so far.  I just need to add some validation in the jQuery

Created a DateTime.cshtml in \Shared\EditorTemplates with the following:

```
 @model System.DateTime?
 @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp" })
```

I added the following jQuery to my DemographicsView.  I plan on testing the jQuery in the _Layout.cshtml to see how it impacts the entire site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dp').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/Images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183647/date-range-validation-with-entity-framework-4-data-annotations)?

Comment: Thanks.  I have considered that type of solution.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some built in feature like the following, which works great.   [Display(Name = "Social Security Number")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please use this format: nnn-nn-nnnn, including the dashes.")]
        public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }

Comment: One option is to pass the date as ticks between client-server. Get the ticks from javascript then convert it to a `DateTime` on the server.

Comment: Post your solution edit as a new answer.

Comment: I will as soon as I get the validation piece in there.  Thank you.